# Posibles soluciones al sistema de usuarios multiples en Rails con Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails

He estado intentando crear una forma ideal de tener múltiples usuarios en Rails. La idea es que solo exista un solo login y un solo registro sin importar la cantidad de modelos de usuarios.

La otra opción sera un solo modelo de usuarios, pero no quiero que todos los campos de todos mis modelos estén en uno solo, ya que como saben hay campos del modelo "Empresa", que no tienen nada que ver con el modelo "Cliente", o Modelo "Asesor", así que me gustaría que ese modelo único ya sea llamado "User" o "Account" solo tuviera campos comunes y los otros modelos los campos respectivos en cada uno de ellos.

Posibles soluciones sin éxito de momento:

1.STI (Single Table Inheritance) Me permite tener una sola tabla, y que los modelos de "Empresa", "Asesor", "Cliente", hereden de ella, pero me obliga a tener todos los campos en el modelo Padre "User" o "Account" dependiendo su nombre, en la intención de poner solo campos comunes en el modelo Padre y poner los campos en los modelos respectivos de manera individual, me es imposible, ya que al heredar de User, no pueden interactuar por si solos con la BD, debido que al heredar quedaría algo asi: Class Enterprise < User, en vez de lo normal que seria: Class Enterprise < ActiveRecord::Base

2.Polimorfismo, esta idea es estupenda, sin embargo al momento de plasmarla, habia obviado de que la empresa, cliente o asesor ya deberian de existir para hacer la conexion con user, de otra forma, userableno sera capaz de encontrar el id y el type del modelo asociado. La idea es que el momento del registro se pregunte que desea ser: "Empresa", "Cliente" o "Asesor", dependiendo lo que pida, se despliegue un nested_form dentro del form del registro, trayendo los campos necesarios desde el modelo de usuario al que seleccione, para que continué completando los campos como: "Tipo de empresa", "Dirección", "Teléfono", etc. Así que en teoría la empresa debería crearse también al momento de registrarse como User donde solo estarán los campos de "Email, Password, Name" y el nested me traerá los campos del modelo al que se hace referencia, tomando como ejemplo los campos de la empresa antes mencionado. Pero para que esto funcione, la empresa ya debe de existir. Asi podra tomar el userable_id, userable_type

Espero puedan ayudarme amigos, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es crear el modelo `User` el cual tenga una relacion con otro modelo que puede ser "Cliente", "Asesor" o "Empresa". De la siguiente manera:

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :client
 belongs_to :enterprise
 belongs_to :asesor

 def entidad
  if self.tipo == "Client"
    self.client
  end
  if self.tipo == "Enterprise"
    self.enterprise
  end
  if self.tipo == "Asesor"
    self.asesor
  end
  null
 end

end
```

Ejemplo de Client.rb, de igual manera seria el Enterprise.rb y el Asesor.rb

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :user
end
```

De tal manera que puedes acceder asi:

```
user.entidad
```

o

```
client.user
```

PD: Otra buena opción es Asociación polimorfa pero no se si va bien en este caso, sin embargo, te recomiendo revisarla.

Comment: Hola Osmond, disculpa te conteste hasta ahora, pero no he tenido la oportunidad de probar esta idea, que me parece bastante interesante, una pregunta aclaratoria de esta: ¿Creas unicamente el user con devise y los otros modelos con client, etc. como modelos normales?

Comment: Claro, así todos se autentificaran con su usuario y tu los trataras dependiendo de su tipo. Ahora en el caso del registro dependería de como lo quieres hacer. Si primero se registran solo el usuario y luego el cliente que lo conecta, o si lo quieres crear al mismo tiempo. Para esas cosas esta la documentación de devise.

Comment: Te entiendo y para que el usuario elija que cuenta quiere seleccionar tendria q haber algun tipo de select me imagino

Comment: Bueno si quieres un select tendrías que generar la vistas de devise y modificarlas, con el comando "rails g devise:views" se generan (revisa en la documentación de devise).

Comment: Si eso te entiendo, es como hasta ahora lo he hecho pero me gustaria tener un solo form, y no 3 en este caso, bueno a todo esto, de que forma manejas los tipos de usuarios y las autenticaciones?